# Make comparison un SQL request

Tags: sql, flask, psql

I got two tables which are defined as below:

```
STATE(NAME varchar,
      POSTALCODE char) 

NB_PRISONERS_STATE(AGE int,
                   SEX char(1), 
                   POSTAL_CODE char, 
                   YEAR integer, 
                   NB integer,
                   LEVEL integer)
```

The two tables can be linked with `STATE.postalcode=NB_PRISONERS_STATE.POSTAL_CODE`

Age is integer and can only be 1 2 or 3
Level is integer and can only be 1 or 2
Sex is char and can only be 'F' or 'M'.

I want to make a request that gives me all the `STATE.name` for a given `YEAR`, a given `LEVEL` where there were more Male than Female put in jail.

I tried

```
Select STATE.name 
from STATE,NB_PRISONERS_STATE 
where STATE.postalcode=NB_PRISONERS_STATE.POSTAL_CODE 
CASE WHEN SUM(select NB_PRISONERS_STATE.nb where NB_PRISONERS_STATE.sexe='H')>SUM(select NB_PRISONERS_STATE.nb where NB_PRISONERS_STATE.sexe='F')
```

Comment: Two things: formatting and code piece you have tried.

Comment: I tried a lot of things but nothing worked

Comment: And sorry I'm a very beginner so I don't know formatting

Comment: I mean just take a look at other questions to understand how to add formatting here. Also know that you are trying to convey your problem to someone who does not know anything about your requirements. So convey all possible details that one might need to answer.

Comment: put your code that you said that is not working and we will see where it needs fixing.

Comment: I edited (added request and NB_PRISONERS_STATE.nb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
SELECT S.NAME
FROM NB_PRISONERS_STATE  P 
INNER JOIN STATE S ON P.POSTAL_CODE=S.POSTALCODE 
WHERE P.YEAR = 2017 AND P.LEVEL=1
GROUP BY S.NAME 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN P.SEX='M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > SUM(CASE WHEN P.SEX='F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

change this accordingly :

```
WHERE P.YEAR = 2017 AND P.LEVEL=1
```

Following your demand :

> all the STATE.name for a given YEAR, a given LEVEL